# How to mount http files?

Tags: filesystems, fuse

I want to mount files that are hosted on an HTTP server such as a video file or an ISO file like NFS shares but with HTTP. For example there is a Linux ISO and I want to see it on my files and copy it to other disks from the server etc. How can I do this? Is it possible to use FUSE filesystem for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are searching for something like https://github.com/fangfufu/httpdirfs

While thinking about it, I realize that WebDAV is just an extension of http. As long as you stay on basic operations you might end up just using http functionality. With this prerequisite, mounting your server via WebDAV might be an option, too. Check out https://savannah.nongnu.org/projects/davfs2

Warning: I quickly used Google and stumbled over it. I do not use such a solution and have no experience with it.

Comment: That's quite helpful but it mounts a whole folder but I need singular files in the same directory from different addresses.

Comment: This sound like a very specific requirement, and finding ready to use implementations might be difficult. But you still can mount all the servers you want (with their complete directory structure), then symlink your choice into yet another folder.

Comment: Tried that but couldn't do it. I'll take a deeper look. Thanks for the reply.